# bind vs bind* in Chicken scheme

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I have the following snippet of Scheme code for Chicken:

```
(require-extension bind)

(bind* "double int_exp(double, int);")
(bind* "double square(double);")

(begin
    (print (int_exp 1.2 1))
    (print (square 2.0)))
```

`int_exp` and `square` are just small test functions (written in C) that I made up for testing. This code works fine; however, as soon as I remove the asterisks, the compiled program prints bogus values (and the bogus values depend on whether I compiled the C code using clang or gcc.) The bind documentation simply [says](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/bind#bind) "[bind* is] similar to bind, but also embeds the code in the generated Scheme expansion using `foreign-declare`" [and](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Accessing%20external%20objects#foreign-declare) "[`foreign-declare` includes] given strings verbatim into header of generated file" - neither is particularly helpful given that I'm new to Chicken (and indeed Scheme.) What do they actually mean, what are the differences between `bind` and `bind*` and when should I use either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, you use `bind` if the function you're calling has already been declared in a header file you've previously `#include`d (including anything automatically included by `chicken.h`, which all Chicken programs include). If the function you're calling is not already declared, then you need to use `bind*` to emit a declaration also.

So, this would work (`math.h` is already included by `chicken.h`):

```
(use bind extras)
(bind "double cbrt(double)")
(format #t "cbrt(~a) = ~a~%" 27 (cbrt 27))
```

Comment: I created a header file for my test functions and included it, and with that the program does work even without the asterisks, but the include still has to be done using `bind*` and even with the include it still works if I use `bind*`, so I'm still not sure how they differ exactly.

Comment: @jaymmer Yes, the `#include` has to be done using `bind*`, as you can see from all the examples. What that does is cause the `#include` (and also the function declarations, if you're using `bind*` for those) to be emitted into the generated C file. If your function declarations matched what's in the header file _exactly_, then using `bind*` for them is harmless. Otherwise, your compiler might baulk....

Comment: You can use `csc -t` to generate the C files without compiling them. Then you can compare what effect using `bind*` has compared to `bind`.